# Order by JPQL Noob

Tags: java, sql, jpql

I am trying to just to have my query ordered by my time stamp column and I cant figure out what is going wrong?

```
String sql = super._jpaql + "where entity.unit.ua=:ua order by timestamp desc";
Query query = super._entityManager.createQuery(sql).setParameter("ua", ua);

List<UnitNotesEntity> list = (List<UnitNotesEntity>) query.getResultList();
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
where entity.unit.ua=:ua order by entity.timestamp desc
```